# CSS: change float columns structural layout?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have three columns where one of the columns is 50% wide and the other two columns are sidebars with 25% width.

**HTML**

```
<article></article>
<aside id="s1"></aside>
<aside id="s2"></aside>
```

**CSS**

```
article {
    width:50%; 
    float:left;
}

aside {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}
```

Maintaining the HTML structure, is it possible to float them in a way to achieve a different layout - I'd like to have `#s1` on the left side of the article and `#s2` on the right side of the article.

**Is this possible with CSS3?** Here is a jsFiddle of the code [above](http://jsfiddle.net/UaFFP/)

Comment: So in the html layout the article layout should come before the 2 asides? As the already given answers show it's so easy to format the asides if the first aside came first. Is keeping the order as is only for readability or because of a template?

Comment: Your HTML should really reflect the structure of your page as much as possible: `<aside id="s1"></aside>` then `<article></article>` and finally `<aside id="s2"></aside>`

Comment: I know it should reflect it I know it goes agains semantics. However in my case I'm building a responsive webdesign where on mobile versions the structure should be like that. It makes sense that the two sidebars are UNDERNEATH the article. However on a desktop device and a wider screen it makes also semantically more sense that the first sidebar is floated to the left of the article … that's why I'm asking!

Comment: … and that is why I don't want to change the markup. The markup is semantic the way it is right now - just on a wider viewport it makes more sense to float it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it without changing the structure of the page - CSS is NOT mean to be used for structural purposes. It completely goes against the principles of semantic markup.

You can easily restructure the page, as in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UaFFP/1/) using HTML to change the structure. Alternatively, @sandeep seems to have a good answer.

Comment: Alright, if it's not possible than this is the correct answer. To understand why I wanted to do this just read my comments on the question itself. It has to do with a responsive layout where it makes real sense to float it differently. However if it's not possible than it's not possible!

Comment: No, sorry! You can always use @media CSS media queries to hide elements and restructure the page on resize though...

Answer (score 1):

Example for two column table structure with css

```
#content {

  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #bbb;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;

  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #bbb;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;

  column-count: 2;
  column-rule: 1px solid #bbb;
  column-gap: 2em;


  display: block;
}​
```

Here is a live demo.

http://playground.html5rocks.com/#columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table` for this. Write like this:

```
article {
    background:#f0f0f0;
    width:50%;
    display:table-cell;
}

aside {
    width:25%;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<aside id="s1"></aside>
<article></article>
<aside id="s2"></aside>
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/UaFFP/2/

Comment: Why would I use `display:table` if I change the order of the html. I could simply float it then the way I want it to be. I don't want to change the markup itself. Check out my comments on the question to understand the reason why I don't want to change the markup.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted S1 to be on the left of the article - so,place it first

```
<aside id="s1"></aside>
```

Then the article

```
<article></article>
```

Then,on the right - you wanted the "s2" - so,place it last

```
<aside id="s2"></aside>
```

Although some changes to the Css will be good - but it works without any changes to the css.